# How to convert a (Java source code) string to (HTML Entity (hex)) string in java?

Tags: java, android, html, string, unicode

I have a string with (java source format) and want to convert it to (Html entity(hex)) to use the target string in webview component.
for more inf see ( http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0068/index.htm ).

for example for word "hello":

> 1-source string is (java source):
>
> "\u0068\u0065\u006C\u006C\u006F"
>
> 2-target must be (html entity):
>
> ```
>  "&#x68;&#x65;&#x6c;&#x6c;&#x6f;"
> ```

I use replaceall(oldstr, newstr) function but it did not work because of "\" character- it is escape char in java.

can any one help me.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\\\u(....)", "&#x$1;");
```

In regex two backslashes represent the backslash itself.
I Java string literals, a backslash is escaped itself too.

So we replace `\u` followed by a group `()` (being `$1`).
This group contains four dots `.` whichs stands for any char except new line characters.

The HTML entity `&...;`is a numeric `#` hexadecimal `x` entity:

```
Java/JS       HTML
\u20ac   ->   &#x20ac;
```

Comment: hi! thanks, it works, but I need to know more about parameters you use in replaceAll("\\\\u(....)", "&#x$1;") expression, such as (....) or $1.

Comment: Extended answer. Regex info can be found undermore in the javadoc of Pattern.